# admob Interstitial show up when game lost

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

I work in a project for a android game and i like to change a intersititial ad method to show up, ad show up when game lost but i like to show up when lost 3 time.

Please help me.

Code for MainActivity.java

```
package com.myboy.to.fly;

import org.cocos2d.layers.CCScene;
import org.cocos2d.nodes.CCDirector;
import org.cocos2d.opengl.CCGLSurfaceView;

import com.myboy.to.fly.R;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.LayoutParams;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {



private CCGLSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView;

//<!-- Admob Ads Using Google Play Services SDK -->
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "";
private static final String AD_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID = "";


/** The Admob ad. */
private InterstitialAd interstitialAd = null;
public AdView adView = null;

public static MainActivity app;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    app = this;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // set view
    mGLSurfaceView = new CCGLSurfaceView(this);


    //Ads ----------------
    // Create the adView
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    //<!-- Ads Using Google Play Services SDK -->
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    // Add the adView to it
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    adView.setLayoutParams(params);

    layout.addView(mGLSurfaceView);
    layout.addView(adView);

    setContentView(layout);
    //New AdRequest 
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    //-----------------------------------------------------Interstitial Add
    // Create an Interstitial ad.
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID);
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
          @Override
          public void onAdLoaded() {
            interstitialAd.show();
          }

          @Override
          public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Interstitial Ads loading failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
    });
     // Load the interstitial ad.
    //showInterstitialAds();

    //----------------------
    // set director
    CCDirector director = CCDirector.sharedDirector();
    director.attachInView(mGLSurfaceView);
    director.setAnimationInterval(1/60);

    // get display info
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    G.display_w = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    G.display_h = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    G.scale = Math.max(G.display_w/1280.0f, G.display_h/800.0f);
    G.width = G.display_w / G.scale;
    G.height = G.display_h / G.scale;

    // get data
    SharedPreferences sp = CCDirector.sharedDirector().getActivity().getSharedPreferences("GameInfo", 0);
    G.music = sp.getBoolean("music", true);
    G.sound = sp.getBoolean("sound", true);

    // create sound
    G.soundMenu = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.menu);
    G.soundMenu.setLooping(true);
    G.soundGame = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.game);
    G.soundGame.setLooping(true);
    G.soundCollide = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.collide);
    G.soundJump = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jump);
    G.soundLongJump = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.long_jump);
    G.soundSpeedDown = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.speed_down);
    G.soundSpeedUp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.speed_up);
    G.soundDirection = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.direction_sign);
    G.soundClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.menu_click);
    G.soundCollect = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.collect);
    G.bgSound = G.soundMenu;

    // show menu
    CCScene scene = CCScene.node();
    scene.addChild(new MenuLayer(true));
    director.runWithScene(scene);
}  

private void adMobInterstitialPresent() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    if (adView != null) {
          adView.pause();
        }

    super.onPause();
    G.bgSound.pause();
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    if (adView != null) {
        adView.resume();
      }

    if( G.music ) G.bgSound.start();

    CCDirector.sharedDirector().onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    // Destroy the AdView.
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.destroy();
    }

    super.onDestroy();
    G.bgSound.pause();
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().end();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
    {
        CCDirector.sharedDirector().onKeyDown(event);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

public void showInterstitialAds()
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
             AdRequest interstitialAdRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
             interstitialAd.loadAd(interstitialAdRequest);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: You can use a counter to achieve this. Increment an integer variable and only show the ads when the value is 3

Comment: Hello can you create for me, i'm beginner on android developer?

Comment: Where would you like to display the ad. Can you show the code you use when the game is lost?

Comment: Meybe this is code 

public void gameOver()
 {
  _mask.runAction(CCFadeIn.action(0.6f));
  _msg.setTexture(CCTextureCache.sharedTextureCache().addImage("game/failed_logo.png"));
  _msg.runAction(CCSequence.actions(
   CCEaseElasticOut.action(CCMoveTo.action(0.6f, G.displayCenter()), 0.5f), 
   CCDelayTime.action(0.5f),
   CCEaseElasticIn.action(CCMoveTo.action(0.6f, CGPoint.ccp(-G.width*0.5f, G.height*0.5f)), 0.5f), 
   CCCallFunc.action(this, "restart")));
  
  MainActivity.app.showInterstitialAds();
 }

Comment: Please add it to your original question